# invisible scrollbar using html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want my scrollbar to be invisible

so that it can't be seen

but when I point to the box it can scroll

and I need to make it work well on the mobile device both tablets and pc. that's why I have chosen html5

I appreciate any help

```css
.scrollable {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 8</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello! Please check that link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll-using-css/
That should help you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add the below line in your CSS file, after that scrollbar will become invisible.

```css
// -webkit- (Chrome, Safari, newer versions of Opera):

.element::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }

// -moz- (Firefox):

.element { overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; }

// -ms- (Internet Explorer +10):

.element { -ms-overflow-style: none; }
```

Comment: @paniwecourf this only works for webkit based browsers so not in firefox, IE or edge

Comment: The answer above doesn’t work for new Mozilla Firefox. See my answer or [this codepen](https://codepen.io/alanhogan/pen/jOpmBKe).

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```css
.scrollable {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.scrollable:hover {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 8</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will handle all current, modern browsers (as of early 2023):

```css
.no-scrollbars {
  scrollbar-width: none; /* FF 64+ */
}
.no-scrollbars::-webkit-scrollbar {
  /* Chromium/Blink, Webkit */
  width: 0 !important;
  height: 0 !important;
}
```

There is no need to use obsolete `-moz-` or `-ms-` CSS anymore. (See also: The [table at the end of my blog post](https://alanhogan.com/code/vendor-prefixed-css-property-names-in-javascript) which lists current vendor prefixes in CSS and JS.)

**Test it yourself [in my CodePen](https://codepen.io/alanhogan/pen/jOpmBKe).**

Please [keep accessibility in mind](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width#accessibility_concerns).